# Why does this character's existence not pose an imbalance of Dark and Light?

Tags: night-watch-cycle, sergei-lukyanenko

Spoilers ahead for books 2 - 6 of the series.

I just finished reading all six books. Fantastic series. There is something that I don't quite understand, however.

Nadya is an absolute enchantress. Throughout the books, at least since the story with the mirror, it is reiterated again and again that the Twilight cares about a balance between Light and Dark.

Why does the presence of an absolute Light One not trigger a mirror? There is also the grandmother of the Conclave of witches switching from Dark to Light; and of course, Anton becoming a Higher Other until the end of the series.

Why is this? I was convinced throughout the sixth book that Nadya would be important. Okay, she ends up being one of the six, but I think Lukyanenko could have written Svetlana in her stead as well; it doesn't strike me as inevitable.

Comment: It’s been a while since I read them all, but I was always under the impression that there were loads of low-powered dark others compared to low powered light others. The Night Watch always seemed busier than the Day Watch.

Comment: Arina is... complicated, in Facebook terms :)  She is a weird Light and a weird Dark, so switching may not really affect the balance all that much.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the presence of an absolute Light One not trigger a mirror?

Because it triggers the Tiger instead. A mirror is insufficient. A mirror is for local imbalance.

And arguably, it triggers the whole book six, though I am not sure causality there is clear.

Comment: My understanding was that the tiger is triggered by Inokentii

Comment: @marts - no, that's just a prophecy. Triggered as in "caused", was by Nadya.

Comment: "The New Watch", Arrowbooks paperback, page 124. Anton, Nadya and others are facing the Tiger. "And suddenly the Tiger spoke. [...] 'Go away. I don't want you.' 'And we don't want YOU', Gesar replied. 'Why don't you go away?' The tiger shook his head. [...] 'The prophecy must not be heard.'"

Comment: "The New Watch", Arrowbooks paperback, pages 264-265: Fan explains the occurence of the Tiger, again only referring to prophets. We learn that the Tiger doesn't want to kill a prophet, and that is a contradiction. In the third story of the same book, the Tiger is satisfied with Arina in the temporal prison. Never touching Nadya. It doesn't make any sense to me that he's been triggered by Nadya.